# Incompatible server error R MonetDBLite()

Tags: r, monetdblite

I have a large MonetDB database I created last year using R DBI::dbWriteTable.  When I try to establish a connection with

```
dbConnect(MonetDBLite(), "~/myfile")
```

returns the error:

```
Error in monetdb_embedded_startup(embedded, !getOption("monetdb.debug.embedded",  : 
  Failed to initialize embedded MonetDB !FATAL: BBPinit: database created with incompatible server:
expected max. integer size 8, got 16.
```

I don't get this error with more recently created Monet databases.  Is this due to a major recent revision? Is there a (relatively) easy way to update the database version?

At terminal  monetdb --version returns "MonetDB Database Server Toolkit v1.1 (Oct2014)". I'm running most recent release of MonetDBLite, DBI etc..

Sorry I'm not including a reproducible example. The database itself is 64GB and I don't know how to randomly sample from it from terminal.

Thanks

Charles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes MonetDB and MonetDBLite databases are currently not compatible. So you would need to export data from the MonetDB database, and then load into MonetDBLite.

Comment: Ah. Thanks very much, Hannes. That explains the behavior. Not quite sure how to export such a large database from MonetDB to MonetDBLite.  Perhaps better for me to just recreate the database in MonetDBLite.